# Deserialize object with references and no default constructor (boost::serialization)

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, reference, default-constructor

Is it possible in boost::serialization library to deserialize (polymorphic) objects with references and no default constructor?

```
class Example
{
    int& value;

public:

    Example(int _value): value(_value) {}
    virtual ~Example() {}

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version)
    {
        ar & value;
    }
};

class Usage
{
    Example* example;

public:

    Usage(): example(new Example(123)) {}
    ~Usage() { delete example; }

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version)
    {
        ar & example;
    }
};
```

...

```
// serialize and deserialize object with reference and no default constructor
{
    Usage source;

    std::ostringstream oss;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(oss);
    oa & source;

    Usage target;

    std::istringstream iss(oss.str());
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(iss);
    ia & target; // does not compile
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for non-default constructible object, I'd recommend to look the item
*Non-Default Constructors*
[here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#constructors).
Your class can be serialized by
writing your own function template `load_construct_data` and `save_construct_data`.

Comment: There is a very annoying asymmetry with these functions though right? That is, if you use `load_construct_data` and `save_construct_data`, you will put/get some of the data to/from the archive, then those functions both call `serialize()`, which may put/get more data to/from the archive. However, then if you try to serialize an object (not a pointer), it will only use `serialize()` which then doesn't put/get all of the data, because it never calls `save/load_construct_data`. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @DavidDoria:
Do you mean `serialize` will be called inside `load_construct_data`?
If I understand correctly, `serialize` is called after `load_construct_data`
has been finished.
`load_construct_data` loads only data required to construct the class
(`m_attribute` in the document linked in the answer),
and `serialize` loads except those(`m_state` in the document).

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. The problem is that this forces serialization to only work with pointer types. That is, if we do Test test; outArchive << test;, only serialize() is called, not save_construct_data. Then since we must use a pointer type to deserialize (Test* readTest; inArchive >> readTest;) it will not work.